# Compare two excel files in Pandas and return the rows which have the same values in TWO columns

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas

I have a couple of excel files. Both the files have two common columns: Customer_Name and Customer_No. The first excel file has around 800k rows while the second has only 460. I want to get a dataframe which has the common data in both the files, ie obtain the rows from the first file that has both the Customer_Name and Customer_No. found in the 2nd file. I tried using .isin but so far I found examples using only a single variable(Column). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Customer_Name','Customer_No'])
```

If you have different column names use `left_on` and `right_on`:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, 
              df2, 
              left_on=['Customer_Name','Customer_No'], 
              right_on=['Customer_head','Customer_Id'])
```

Comment: But I'm getting a KeyError instead. I have checked the data types of the columns and made sure they're the same too. :(

Comment: Pleasae check column names - `df2.columns`, maybe there is some space before text - like `'    Customer_head'`. Or maybe problem is  do you have  in `df1` `left_on` columns and in `df2` `right_on` columns?

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC and you don't need extra columns from the second file - it will be used just for joining, you can do it this way:

```
common_cols = ['Customer_Name','Customer_No']

df = (pd.read_excel(filename1)
        .join(pd.read_excel(filename2, usecols=common_cols),
                            on=common_cols))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the direct way will be like this:

```
df_file1 = pd.read_csv(file1, index_col) # set Customer_No
df_file2 = pd.read_csv(file2, index_col) # set Customer_No
for index, row in df_file1.iterrows():
    if row.get_value('Customer_name) in df_file2['Customer_name'].values:
```

here you can count, simply by integer or produce some complicated job like add [index, row] to result df, if needed.